# Handing nullls as alias at pig level

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, bigdata

​Hi All,

I have my table structure and  in hive like below .

```
Create table hv (x int,y int,z int ,w int )
```

PIGLATIN used to load the table

```
A  = LOAD 'XYZ.CSV.GZ' using pigstorage AS (x,y,w)
```

this time  Z col  is missing from the file so i wan to keep the value of z as null in PIGLATIN and i donot want to change my hive table structure .How to generate the values as null for this column in pig??

Answer (score 0):

with reference to [Nulls and constants](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.15.0/basic.html#nulls) you can do something like this:

```
--load your hive table
A = LOAD 'hive_db.table_name' USING org.apache.hive.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

--this will generate a NULL column with datatype bytearray
B = FOREACH A GENERATE X,Y,NULL,W;

--then you can further process your data
STORE B INTO '/your/hdfs' USING PigStorage(',');
```